# Adding different users to azure bot service

Tags: azure, botframework, rbac, azure-bot-service

I have created different Web App Bots in azure portal. I want to different users into azure portal and assign bot to each. 
    So when they login , they will only see the bot service assigned to them and they will work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each Web App Bot, set the right users in `Access Control`